# Debug routes for specific controller

Tags: symfony, console

Is it possible to debug routes for special controller like :

```
php app/console router:debug PlayersController
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, not like that. But you could just output all routes with their assigned controllers and then grep on the controller you want to debug. E.g.:

```
php app/console router:debug --show-controllers | grep PlayersController
```

Or in the PowerShell in case you're stuck on Windows:

```
php app/console router:debug --show-controllers | Select-String -Pattern "PlayersController"
```